# Web Forms how to turn off authorization on Api Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-authorization

I have old web form application with Windows authentication setted up on web.config like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

I have add new controller like this:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
    };

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
}
```

And i don't wont have authorization on it.

My problem is:
When i try use postman to get Product on query .../api/Test i got 401, but when i go to this page from browser it's work.

I try to add this on webconfig:

```
 <location path="Controller">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

or

```
    <location path="Controller/Test">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

But this don't want to work :(
Did You have some other solution?